# R lmer4 package multilevel model adding random effect with 0 notation

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I do not understand what the difference between these two models is ( I am using the lmer4 package)

```
Model.1<-lmer(Y~ X1+ X2+ X3
          +(1|Subject) + (0+X1|Subject)+ (0+X2|Subject), 
          data=Data, REML=FALSE)

Model.2<-lmer(Y~ X1+ X2+ X3
          +(1|Subject) + (X1|Subject)+ (X2|Subject), 
          data=Data, REML=FALSE)
```

When I compare these two models, I get different degrees of freedom (with model 1 having less than model 2). But I am not sure what the (0+..) notation does to the random effect, and how I decide on a theoretical level which model to use (other than comparing BIC scores).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Model.2` doesn't make much sense because you are asking the software to estimate random intercepts for `Subject` three times. That is because:

```
(1|Subject) + (X1|Subject)+ (X2|Subject)
```

is the same as:

```
(1|Subject) + (1 + X1|Subject) + (1 + X2|Subject)
```

where the `1` in each term specifies that you want random intercepts for the term on the right side of the `|`.

The `0 + X1` on the left side of the random effects terms in `model.1` tells the software to estimate random slopes for `X1` but *not* random intercepts for `Subject`, and since you also have `(1|Subject)` which *does* fit random intercepts for `Subject, this is how you specify random slopes that are *not* correlated with random intercepts. Note that another way to write:

```
(1 | Subject) + (0 + X1 | Subject)
```

is to write:

```
(X1 || Subject)
```

So your `Model.1` could be re-written more compactly as:

```
lmer(Y~ X1+ X2+ X3 + (X1 + X2 || Subject)
```

which is different from:

```
lmer(Y~ X1+ X2+ X3 + (X1 + X2 | Subject)
```

because in this case the software would estimate correlations between both random slopes and the random intercepts.